# Custom validation with validates_each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activemodel

I'm trying to implement custom validation with `validates_each` method. I have **rules.json** file where I keep my rules for validation. In this case I want to validate that the `gender` value is included in `["Male", "Female"]` array and the `title` in `["Mr", "Mrs"]` array.

With `self.parse_rules` method I parse json file and with `self.all_funders(attribute)` I access gender and title values `["Male", "Female"], ["Mr", "Mrs"]`.

When I run the `validates_each` method for `:gender, :title` I'm only able to validate both attributes on `["Male", "Female"]` array, therefore `:title` will always give an error message **"Error message"**.

For some reasons I don't understand `["Mr", "Mrs"]` array is not fetched from json file when validations processing. Can anyone advise on how do I solve this issue?

```
class Rule
 include ActiveModel::Validations

 attr_accessor :gender, :title

 def self.parse_rules
  JSON.parse(File.read("rules.json"))
 end

 def self.all_funders(attribute)
  @all_rules ||= parse_rules[attribute.to_sym][:options]
 end

 validates_each :gender, :title do |record, attr, value|
  record.errors.add(attr, "Error message") if !all_funders(attr).include?(value)
 end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're memoizing the specific attribute in `all_funders` instead of the entire json. If you were to replace `validates_each :gender, :title` with `validates_each :title, :gender` `:title` would always work and `:gender` would always error. To fix this you'll probably want to change `all_funders` to look more like:

```
def self.all_funders(attribute)
  @all_rules ||= parse_rules

  @all_rules[attribute.to_sym][:options]
end
```

So here, we're memoizing the result of loading/parsing the file (so `@all_rules` becomes the parsed hash of the entire file) and then looking at the specific attribute asked for.

Another alternative would be to memoize in the `parse_rules` method:

```
def self.parse_rules
  @all_rules ||= JSON.parse(File.read("rules.json"))
end

def self.all_funders(attribute)
  parse_rules[attribute.to_sym][:options]
end
```

to make it more clear (IMO) what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

The first call to `all_funders` memoizes the result. This result will be returned on all subsequent calls, regardless of the method parameters. To fix the bug, memoize `parse_rules` instead.

Here is a repo that [shows how your bug is occurring when `all_funders` is called multiple times](https://github.com/applandinc/land-of-applets/tree/master/custom-validation-with-validates-each_62637786). The repo includes a demonstration program as well as static images and an interactive depiction of how the bug is occurring.